# Processing PImage Array stays in memory

Tags: java, processing

I have a simple processing sketch where pictures get read into a PImage Array. (on key press small letter). If I press a capital letter the sketch is supposed to reset everything or at least null the image array. But I cannot get this done. The memory allocates spaces and its consumption keeps on growing. When resetting the app the draw call still renders the images (line 18). Here is my code:

```
PImage[] images;
PImage photo;
int counter;
void setup()
{
  //Storage of image replicas
  images = new PImage[0];
  //Image instance that gets copied on key press
  photo = loadImage("x.png");
  size(500, 500);  
}
void draw()
{
  //Image instance
  image(photo,0,0);
  for(int i= 0; i < images.length; i++){
    //copied instances from images
    image(images[i], i*50, 100);
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  int keyIndex = -1;
  if (key >= 'a' && key <= 'z') {
    println("copy iamge and save in PImage Array");
    PImage tmpImg = get(0,0,50,50);
    images = (PImage[]) expand(images, images.length+1);
    images[counter] = tmpImg;
    counter++;
  }
  else if (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z') {
    //attempt to reset image cache
    for (int i=0; i< images.length; i++) {
      println("attempt to reset cache");
      g.removeCache(images[i]);
    }
    println("attempt to reset PImage Array");
    images = null;
    images = new PImage[0];
    counter = 0;
    //attempt to call setup to reset PImage Array
    setup();
  }
}
```

Any help is much apprecaited!

Comment: This code (taking out the video stuff) seems to work for me. Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that does **not** include any video stuff, so we can run it on our computers? Also, try adding print statements- is that else-if statement being entered?

Comment: Hi Kevin thanks for your reply. I tried to edit my post as MCVE compatible as possible. The only dependency I could not recreate is the data/x.png that I load on line 9. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing does not automatically clear out old frames- it just draws on top of whatever was there. You can prove that with this little sketch:

```
void draw(){
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

To clear out old frames, you have to specifically tell Processing to draw a background, like so:

```
void draw(){
  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

Your code actually **is** clearing out the old images, but you never clear out the old frames, so they're still visible.

Just call the background() function in the first line of your draw() function.

As for your memory usage going up, this might be normal. Do you run out of memory, or does the garbage collector eventually kick in?

Comment: That's it, stupid me. It is not clearing the frame automatically. In the original sketch I'm working with HD-resoluted pictures from the cam, what explains the hight memory consumption. The garbage collector however seems not to kick in as expected and even after running setup() the memory-consumption in Activity-Monitor stays the same. I have to do stress tests on the target device though, in order to see whether memory is released or whether I run into a nasty Out of Memory Error. The only way to get the memory back so far, is to restart Processing. Thx Kevin, your help is much appreciated!